# Ag grid with Async Pipe + New Data

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

The first time I come to my component the Loading overlay works properly.

```
        this.filteredTasks$ = this.taskService.getQueuesFilteredTasks(httpParams);


      <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 550px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [rowData]="filteredTasks$ | async" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
        (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

How am i supposed to properly show the Loading overlay when that line of code is hit again? This seems like a very common occurrence.

Currently it just displays "No Rows to Show"

Below is my workaround

```
        this.filteredTasks$ = this.taskService.getQueuesFilteredTasks(httpParams);
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.gridOptions.api) {
            this.gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();
        }
    }, 1);
```

Have they fixed this in a newer version by chance? Below is my version.

```
"ag-grid": "17.0.0",
"ag-grid-angular": "17.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "17.0.0",
```

Comment: take a look to rxjs ` finallize` or `await` it's not good practice to use timeouts

Comment: The problem with a finalize is at that point the new data will already have been loaded in. Completely removing the need for me to show the "Loading" at that point since the data is already loaded.